Socket connection to localhost refused
I have a Java Spring Boot application that at the service level creates a Socket connection to localhost and accesses another application written in C++.
When I run a Java application on a remote host and call this line, an error occurs:
Socket socket = new Socket("localhost", port);

java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
         at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect0(Native Method)  
         at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:579)   
         at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:568)  
         at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.connect(NioSocketImpl.java:593) 
         at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:327) 
         at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:633)   
         at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:583) 
         at java.base/java.net.Socket.(Socket.java:507)    
         at java.base/java.net.Socket.(Socket.java:287) 

But at the same time, if I change the host to external IP, everything works fine.
Socket socket = new Socket("IP-Address", port); 
The port that the C++ application uses has "Inbound" and "Outbound" Rules for TCP/UDP requests and it's open.
Any ideas what is wrong here?

Are you running both applications in the same server?

may seem silly, but did you try 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost? maybe that its not resolved on that machine with that OS to 127.0.0.1

@aled Yes, on the same one

@Gewure I already tried changing to 127.0.0.1, it didn’t help

Are you sure localhost is defined in that server? What is the c++ app listening to? Provide more details. However it seems a networking issue, not a programming issue.

@aled Yes, I am sure that localhost is defined, since I have "server.host=localhost" property in the application.properties file and this property is used by Spring Boot and works fine. The C++ application is a PvPGN server, it has a complex and huge implementation to share here.

Most likely, the C++ server is binding only to the external IP address and not to the loopback address. This is probably something you can configure for the server.

Post output for netstat (listening) searching on the port

@g00se In NetStat, in the "Connections" tab, the Local Port that the C++ server application uses has the status "LISTEN", "Remote Address" and "Remote Port" has "N/A" value. Is it enough or should I get some kind of output? If yes, how can I do this?

That seems OK. You found the port. What is the actual address?

@g00se "Local Address" is equal to external IP, "Protocol" is  TCP.

If by "external IP" you mean one that's publicly routeable, then there will be almost certainly an authentication mechanism in play. How are you handling that?

@g00se This is a VPS server, I don't know much about networks, sorry. I just know that I have no problems making REST API calls to it via Swagger or Postman from my machine on a host that is the external IP address of the VPS server. There is only a problem with establishing a Socket connection via localhost.

You're intending to make REST calls to it via this socket?

@g00se No, it's a Spring Boot application with a registration controller. When the user registers in UI, registration endpoint works and in the first step of the service levels I create a Socket connection to the cpp (game server) app and send username and email of the user to register the player. I'm doing this because the cpp app doesn't have any type of MVC or Controllers, it only has socket functionality. After that, I check response via socket connection from the cpp app (game server), if response is successful, I register user in database via JPA, Hibernate in another table.

@Neo "When I run a Java application on a remote host and call this line, an error occurs:" - that implies the Java app and the C++ server are NOT running on the same machine, in which case localhost will not work, you would need the network IP of the machine that the C++ server is actually running on.
